# The choice is clear: burninate [multiple-choice-question]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Currently sitting with 0 followers, 4 questions and no usage guidance, I think we should burninate [multiple-choice-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-choice-question).

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

All 4 questions are asking about different things. Two are about using completely different frameworks and the other two would stand alone fine without the tag.

**Is the concept described even in-topic for the site?**

Multiple choice questions aren't inherently technical so I don't believe so.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No, with the possible exception of a question on SAKAI the tag does nothing to aid in answering the question.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Not really. Sure, it always references a multiple choice question but the context for that is always different.

All in all, I really can't imagine this tag being helpful to anyone in the future. The only reason I can see someone searching for a solution to a [multiple-choice-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-choice-question) is if they're looking for a solution to a homework problem.

Comment: 1 exception of 4?

Comment: With only 4 questions, I think you could have done it yourself. Or did you just want to quizz Meta for the best pun :D?

Comment: @Tunaki Mostly that ;) Also, I wanted to get feedback on if I should proceed. Looks like I ought to.

Comment: @Tunaki: All of the above? ;-)

Comment: we could: a) burninate or b) massternate [multiple-choice-question]

Comment: Why do they call it multiple choice when you can only make one?

Comment: @Magoo multiple choices available, not selected.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Which of these is the correct answer?

- A) The tag was left alone
- B) The tag was added to more questions
- C) The tag was burninated
- D) All of the above

The correct answer: **C**.

Comment: Easy one! Just 4 questions to re-tag. I challenge you to burninate [PHP].

Comment: This answer is a gross misuse of our self-answering Q&A system. /s

Comment: We all need a humor break once in a while.

Comment: The correct answer: Mike C.