# To Burn, or Not to Burn [multiple-choice]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, tag-blocklist

[multiple-choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-choice) currently has 233 questions from different domains and programming languages. It has a tag wiki:

> Multiple choice is a form of assessment in which respondents are asked to select the best possible answer (or answers) out of the choices from a list. The multiple choice format is most frequently used in educational testing, in market research, and in elections.

A very similar tag [multiple-choice-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-choice-question) dealing with this was previously burninated [The choice is clear: burninate [multiple-choice-question]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317173/the-choice-is-clear-burninate-multiple-choice-question).

**Is the concept described even in-topic for the site?**
No

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**
Other than the offtopic questions asking for solution for their multiple choice questions, the rest of the questions deal with *creating* multiple choice format in different languages/technologies. It seems like a meta tag.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
No.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
It all refers to multiple choice format in different contexts.

In my opinion, this needs to be burninated if not blocklisted.

Comment: Blacklisting seems a bit overkill, I doubt it is that big of a problem.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica I added blocklisting as this seems to be [the second time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317173/the-choice-is-clear-burninate-multiple-choice-question) this type of tag has come up

Comment: Oh, my bad. I didn’t realize that.

Comment: ☐ Burn [multiple-choice]. ☐ Do not burn [multiple-choice]. ☐ All of the above. ☐ None of the above.

Comment: @honk yeah, this feels more of a binary choice rather than multiple.

Comment: "Alas, poor Trogdor! I knew him well."

Comment: @honk: you left out **☐ 1 and 2** and **☐ 3 & 4**

Comment: @honk all of the above

Answer (score 6):

For the questions I looked at with the [multiple-choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-choice) tag, dropping the [multiple-choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-choice) tag would not hurt the understandability of the question IMO.

As @suraj mentions, the questions involve so many different technologies, the tag doesn't IMO help locate questions unless you also use another tag to identify the technology.

Searching for **[multiple choice java](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=multiple%20choice%20java)** does a decent job at finding questions (1,391 results) that deal with the topic of multiple choice versus using the tag [multiple-choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-choice) (which gives [46 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmultiple-choice%5D%20java)).

I don't think it's a huge deal to leave it around, especially if it's going to create argument/discussion.  It's just not worth it (IMO).

I would (at a minimum) no longer allow the tag to be used and see no real harm in removing the tag from the questions.  But I personally would rather not change questions and *history*.

With that said, I'm new to responding on meta questions, so I don't have a deep understanding of how these kinds of issues have been dealt with in the past.

Comment: Typically we're less conservative than that about retagging existing questions to categorize them properly.  The edit history is still going to be there for any individual questions if people want to see how something was originally tagged, but as you argue there's negligible current value in having the tag exist.